# Grouping fields with field group doesn't work on display of Drupal Commerce product in product variation

Tags: commerce, entities

I've got a content type for a product and fields for variation. I'm writing about fields in that variation. I have created new group containing some fields using field groups.
Let's say:

```
[Field group]
 1. Foo
 2. Bar
```

The group setup is done properly on content type/field display in product variation tab. I'm using drupal commerce, I have tried updating CRON, flushing cache, drinking beer, resaving content. It didn't help. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module provides the ability to group on both the edit form and the display independently.

This means to add a field group to the form you have to do so on `admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENTTYPE` and to add a field group for display you do it on `admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENTTYPE/display` (this is for nodes, this will be in different places for other entity types).

If you want the group on both the form and the display you have to add it in both places.

Comment: The answer doesn't address the question, which was regarding Field Group with the Commerce Product Form Management User Interface.

Currently, the field grouping capabilities doesn't work as of May 28th, 2015 with the latest modules installed.

Answer (score 0):

My specific question instead of normal nodes was about **drupal commerce product**. Everything is ok if you create group for a content type and select for ex. `<div>` wrapper. But groups are not showing when you change display in product variation (`product-variation-types/product/display`) and they also don't work with HTML5 wrapper (*see bottom*).

I've got code like this

```
<div> 
    <label></label><field></field>
</div>
<div> 
    <label></label><field></field>
</div>
<div> 
    <label></label><field></field>
</div>
<div> 
    <label></label><field></field>
</div>
<div> 
    <label></label><field></field>
</div>
```

And I wanted to put the fields into a group:

```
<div id="field-group">
    <div> 
        <label></label><field></field>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <label></label><field></field>
    </div>
</div>
    <div> 
        <label></label><field></field>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <label></label><field></field>
    </div>
```

*HTML5 wrapper bug*
But the result after selecting **HTML5 wrapper** was:

```
<div>
    <id="field-group">
    <div> 
        <label></label><field></field>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <label></label><field></field>
    </div>

    <div> 
        <label></label><field></field>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <label></label><field></field>
    </div>
</div>
```